# Do I need a jQuery to use the ng2-bootstrap Date_picker?

Tags: jquery, angular-ui-bootstrap

I using angular.
I using ng2-bootstrap.
I want to use a Data_picker.
I do not want jQuery to use it.
Can I use the data picker without jQuery?

Is there a sample somewhere?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker#examples

Answer (score 0):

https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker

It was possible in the explanation here.

Comment: But I can not pop up.

Comment: but the design and the text box of bootstrap are different.I want to change textbox design. It was useless to do "add class='form-control'"